# Tomcat to oracle channel encryption using transparent data encryption

Tags: oracle, tomcat, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration, tde

We just want to encrypt communication channel between application (tomcat) and database (oracle). Also  JDBC and ODBC channels need to be encrypted as our application uses both JDBC and ODBC. We tried to follow oracle pdf but couldn't achieve it.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Oracle Wallets or Java Key Stores(JKS) ? check out the [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc%2C-tlsv12%2C-jks-or-oracle-wallets) for details.